# Remote desktop (RDP) fails on AWS EC2

Tags: windows-7, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services, rdp

I have good access to my AWS EC2 machine using my browser (surfing websites) and FTP (uploading and downloading).

However, it so happends that in many occasions, when trying to connect using RDP from my Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008 on my remote machine, I either get a black screen, a static snapshot or getting thrown out.

In few occasions I am able to connect successfully and for a good number of hours.

What can be the case and what should I do ?

**UPDATE**

I'm still having the same problem with RDP.

However, I installed Logmein on both machines and the remote computer is controlled extremely well, with good feedback and high frame rate.

This leads me to think that the internet connection is good is that the problem might be with the RDP port of 3389.

What do you think ?

Comment: Do you have several instance running? Are they load balanced?

Comment: No, there is no load on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had, "the same", symptoms.

If you happen to use VOIP (Voice (phone service) Over IP), definitely explore this (my resolution below) further.  If you happen to utilize QOS (Quality Of Service) protocol, consider testing without that feature on.

I resolved this issue by **replacing** my WRT54GP2 linksys Router.  This router had built in support for Vonage.  Just *bypassing* it's built in Vonage support did not help.  Using it *only* for Vonage support did not help.  Only replacing the router with another one, resolved the problem. (I now utilize a WRV200 linksys router and a separate Vonage phone adapter.)

Note that my WRT54GP2 was, in all other ways, functioning well.

Comment: You know what? Although my router served me for a long time, I suspected it so I went and replaced it and walla! RDP is running better than ever !!